# Can an old Xcode 3.2 based project be run using Xcode 10?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode3.2

What things needs to changed or updated to run the a project created using Xcode 3.2 in Xcode 10? So, far I have changed the architecture to standard architecture and deployment target to iOS 10.0. Previously it was iOS 5.0, and supported device was iPhone 7 plus. I have also deleted Info.plist. But now I am getting the following error:

[image]

Also would like to mention that CocoaPods isn't used in the project. Has anyone faced similar issue and were able to resolve it?

Comment: Does the blurred filename in the screenshot belong to project or a system framework? Can you go to the Terminal and check by running `ls -l` corresponding to the file to check if you have the ownership and appropriate permission for the file?

Comment: @NimeshNeema it's the app name file

Comment: What function does the file serve in the project? Is it listed under Project file → Build Phases → Compile Sources? Did you manage to run the command listed in the first comment?

Comment: Might be simpler to start a new project and just copy/paste text as needed. Storyboards might have to be reconstructed from scratch.